# Downloading a database from the cloud to Android

Tags: android, mysql, database, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am pretty new to databases but I have an idea I'm trying to implement and I'm looking for some answers on if I'm going down the right path here.

I'm trying to create an app that displays locations in a list or on a map. The locations are going to be stored in a MySQL database hosted by Amazon Web Services. When the user opens the map portion of the app the database will be queried and the locations within the map view will be displayed. I figure the database won't be super big (around 10k locations) so I think it would be best to download the entire database and store it client-side on the users cell phone. There would have to be some kind of version check to determine if the user has the latest version of the database. Where would the version of the db be stored? Does the database or table automatically have a version number that increments automatically?

Second part of the question - is downloading the entire database (although small) a good idea? It seems like it would cut down on multiple database accesses per session and use less network traffic (anytime the user moves the map they would have to query for more locations within that area). I'm just trying to figure out if this is the best way to go about doing this since I'm brand new with databases. Thanks for any input.

Comment: you can just build a webservice to get the location based on query from client. Android cannot open MySQL database, instead you can download the data with webservice then insert it into SQLite if you want store the data in client. But i think the best approach is just store the data in server and using webservice to get data what client want

Comment: can you expand on why a web service is needed? Can't I just ask the database directly from the client?

Comment: how you do that? android cannot read mysql database

Answer (score 0):

Android has support for SQLite when it comes to embedded databases.
First you should check the compatibility between MySQL and SQLite SQL if you want to download the entire database. 
Also, in android there is a class called [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html%20SQLiteOpenHelper) which has an onUpdate method that comes handy when one must update the database.
In my experience, I would recommend using a web service instead of downloading the entire database, mainly because of bandwidth and security issues.